# Entity Framework Connection Error "Cannot open database "DB" requested by the login. The login failed"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework in .NET MVC 3.0 and use Code First method.
And I used a .MDF file for database and also use "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" to generate database automatically after every change.

My application works correct, but when I open database from Server Explorer in VS, then my application gives an error:

> Cannot open database "DB" requested
>   by the login. The login failed. Login
>   failed for user 'Mahdi-PC\Mahdi

Could you help me?!

Comment: _Presuambly_ the process that creates the DB has different credentials to you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but... In the Data Connection dialog have you got the "Data Source" set to "Microsoft SQL Server" - I think you might need to change it to be "Microsoft SQL Server Database File"

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had the `mdf` file open in **SQL SMS 2012** while I was trying to `update-database` in **Visual Studio 2013** *Package Manager Console*. In my case **VS 2013** and **SQL SMS 2012** could not share the `mdf` file. Once I closed **SQL SMS** I was able to update the `mdf` file ... that was whack ...

Comment: That's not a login failure. That's trying to drop a database while it's connected.